# How to test push notification in android and iOS using Appium in ruby

Tags: android, ios, ruby, push-notification, appium

I am using Appium with ruby to write automation scripts, there are notification generated in some functionality. How do I test it (both android and iOS), any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

with Appium it works for [Android only](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/system/open-notifications/):

```
@driver.open_notifications();
```

Comment: Important to note this only works on emulated devices.